# deleting a record which selected by user?

Tags: java, mysql

I am coding

```
String Name = txtName.getText();
String Surname = txtSurname.getText();  
st.executeUpdate("DELETE from list WHERE Name=@Name and Surname=@Surname");
```

but it doesn't delete the records. Any problem with the syntax? Please help.

Comment: Side note: youShouldTry[LowerCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `@name` and `@surname` with the actual values.

and add `'` around your values:

```
DELETE from list WHERE Name='@Name' and Surname='@Surname'


String Name = txtName.getText().Trim();
String Surname = txtSurname.getText().Trim();  
String query = "DELETE from list WHERE Name='" + Name + "' and Surname='" + Surname + "'";
st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: no error with this syntax but it doesnt delete the record as well

Comment: @KutluhanMetin: Did you trim your name and surname before adding to your query? Maybe you have some spaces in there.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
st.executeNonQuery("DELETE from list WHERE Name=?e and Surname=?");
```

and pass the name and surname as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

If the table list  exists .

This will work .

```
String Name = txtName.getText();
String Surname = txtSurname.getText();  


st.executeUpdate("DELETE from list WHERE Name='"+Name"' and Surname='"+Surname"'");
```

I fixed it like that:

```
st.executeUpdate("DELETE from list WHERE Name='"+txtName.getText()+"'" + "and Surname='" + txtSurname.getText()+"'");
```

Thank you all

Comment: the table exists. But It still says there s something wrong with your syntax